Calculate distances between all point features in one layer and all point features in another layer (NOT only nearest)
I would like to calculate distances between all point features in one layer and all point features in another layer using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 tools or ModelBuilder. I'm not looking for distance to the nearest point but instead distances between all points (aka distance matrix). I have tried Near, Generate Near Table and Spatial Join with multiple combinations and only manage to get the nearest distances. The Network Analyst -toolbox won't work as I'm looking for Euclidean distance. I have the Advanced-level license.
If my first point layer looks like this:



Point_id
Value




1
0.3


2
0.5


...
...



And  my second point layer looks like this:



Point_id
Value




1
1025


2
2055


...
...



I would like the end layer/table look like this:



Point_id
Value
Point_id2
Value2
Distance




1
0.3
1
1025
10.2


2
0.5
2
2055
20.6


...
...
'''
...
...



The answer could be "No, there's no way of doing this in ArcGIS Pro tools, instead you have to use ArcPy, or Python outside the software."

I think you should try the Generate Near Table (Analysis) tool with its closest="ALL" option so that:

Multiple near features will be written to the output table

Otherwise, by default, only rows for the nearest features are written to the output table, as you have observed.
